# Detect if WP is running under WP-CLI

Tags: wp-cli

I use the wonderful [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) tool. Due to dependence on Apache environment variables for a specific use case, I need to enable a bit of code to run only when running under WP-CLI. **How can I detect if WP is running under WP-CLI?**

In this specific case I *could* check for the presence of the Apache environment variables in question. However, I would like to know the more general, canonical method to check. Thank you.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Within the [`php/wp-cli.php`](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/71626710db27d5202e4df063c5b664fd5eb6615c/php/wp-cli.php#L3-6) we find these lines:

```
// Can be used by plugins/themes to check if WP-CLI is running or not
define( 'WP_CLI', true );
define( 'WP_CLI_VERSION', trim( file_get_contents( WP_CLI_ROOT . '/VERSION' ) ) );
define( 'WP_CLI_START_MICROTIME', microtime( true ) );
```

so you could check if `WP_CLI` or `WP_CLI_VERSION` are defined.

Comment: `WP_CLI` is the preferred constant to check

Comment: Thanks for commenting - yes and also much shorter, was just wondering about other possibilities ;-) @DanielBachhuber

Comment: @dotancohen you should consider accepting the answer by Ryan McCue instead, as it shows explicitly how to check it.

Comment: @birgire, may I ask you to have a look at a custom field related question here : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/265852/set-and-unset-the-custom-field-value ?

Answer (score 40):

The canonical check for WP-CLI, which is used in most plugins and is explicitly mentioned [in the docs](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/guides/commands-cookbook/#include-in-a-plugin-or-theme), is the check whether `WP_CLI` is defined and set to true:

```
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) && WP_CLI ) {
    // Do WP-CLI specific things.
}
```