# set and unset the custom field value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, post-thumbnails

While showing all the posts together in admin panel, I have a custom column 'Featured Image'. And this column has a value YesOrNO.

To set the column name : I have inside functions.php:

```
function set_column_heading($defaults) {
    $defaults['featured_image'] = 'Featured Image';
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'set_column_heading');
```

In order to set the column value, I have :

```
 function set_column_value($column_name, $post_ID) {
        if ($column_name == 'featured_image') {
            $post_featured_image = get_featured_image($post_ID);
            if ($post_featured_image) {
                echo 'YesOrNO';
            }
        }
    }

    function get_featured_image($post_ID) {
        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_ID);
        if ($post_thumbnail_id) {
            $post_thumbnail_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, 'featured_preview');
            return $post_thumbnail_img[0];
        }
    }
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'set_column_value', 10, 2);
```

Yes , I get the column name and value (i.e. YesOrNo) as I expected. In wordpress frontend, I want to show the featured images of posts with a condition. The condition is : I need a click handler on the column value (i.e. YesOrNo) so that I can toggle it as chosen or unchosen and I like to show featured images from the chosen ones only.

How can I do that ?

Comment: I'd suggest creating a new meta value called `_show_featured_image` which will be used to determine if the image should be shown on the frontend or not. Then, in addition to displaying this value within the admin columns, you will need to create an ajax handler to allow users to toggle the value. [Here is a great looking post which deals with something similar](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33442/custom-column-for-changing-post-status-via-ajax) (toggling post status) which should help to to accomplish that.

Comment: @DaveRomsey, trying to understand the solution you referred to. Can you shed a bit more light i.e. attaching the click handler and making or freeing `YesOrNo` from a focused state (i.e bold) wrt to toggling it  ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have enough time. I'd suggest doing your best and adding all of your code representing your best effort to the answer. Right now, the question is pretty broad so I think narrowing things down will bring more eyes to your question. Implement the solution from the answer I linked to and try and understand how it is working. Then fork that plugin into a new version and start modifying it to suit your needs (modifying meta instead of post status).

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is almost 2 years too late, but I hope it's still useful to some people that land here looking for an answer.

**Disclaimer:** this is not a great pattern according to WordPress admin design patterns, but it's actually nice to use in a pinch.

> Insert the following into your functions.php file in your theme

### Set your admin column heading

```
function set_column_heading( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['featured_image'] = 'Featured Image';
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'set_column_heading' );
```

### Set your admin column value

This has changed to handle the current status of whether or not the featured image is set to be displayed by fetching [post meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/). It also handles the [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

```
function set_column_value( $column_name, $post_ID ) {
    if ( 'featured_image' === $column_name ) {
        $post_featured_image = get_featured_image( $post_ID );
        if ( $post_featured_image ) {
            $featured_image_display = get_post_meta( $post_ID, 'show_featured_image' );
            $show_class             = 'show';
            $show_text              = 'Display Featured Image';
            if ( $featured_image_display ) {
                $show_class = 'hide';
                $show_text  = 'Hide Featured Image';
            }
            echo '<button class="' . esc_attr( $show_class ) . '" data-nonce="' . esc_attr( wp_create_nonce( 'my_display_featured_image_' . $post_ID ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $show_text ) . '</button>';
        }
    }
}

function get_featured_image( $post_ID ) {
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_ID );
    if ( $post_thumbnail_id ) {
        $post_thumbnail_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'featured_preview' );
        return $post_thumbnail_img[0];
    }
}
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'set_column_value', 10, 2 );
```

### Enqueue your script on the post list page.

This is pretty simple. Make sure your script path is correct and jQuery is a dependency.

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_admin_scripts' );
function my_enqueue_admin_scripts( $hook ) {
    if ( 'edit.php' !== $hook ) {
        return;
    }
    wp_enqueue_script( 'set_featured_image', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/set-featured-image.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
```

### Register an admin-only ajax response function

This response to the ajax request we have in our javascript, `set-featured-image.js`. This updates the [post meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) to reflect the status. It also handles the [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) verification.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_display_featured_image', 'my_display_featured_image' );
function my_display_featured_image() {
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['featuredImage'], $_POST['postID'] ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( array( 'isset' ) );
        wp_die();
    }
    if ( ! is_numeric( $_POST['postID'] ) ) {
        wp_send_json_error( array( 'checks' ) );
        wp_die();
    }

    $post_id = intval( $_POST['postID'] );
    check_ajax_referer( 'my_display_featured_image_' . $post_id );

    $set_featured_image = wp_validate_boolean( $_POST['featuredImage'] );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'show_featured_image', $set_featured_image );

    wp_send_json( array( 'featuredImage' => $set_featured_image ) );
    wp_die();
}
```

> Insert the following into the new script you're enqueuing, `set-featured-image.js`

### Handle the click event and ajax request

When you click the button the correct data is put together, handles the UI changes, and sends the data to our ajax response handler in PHP, `my_display_featured_image()`. Once we get a response, it updates the button status to reflect the correct value we stored in post meta.

```
(function($) {
  $('.featured_image button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $button = $(this);
    var display = false;
    if($button.hasClass('show')) {
      display = true;
    }
    var postID = $button.parents('tr').attr('id').replace(/post-/g, '');
    $button.attr('disabled', true);
    var data = {
      action: 'my_display_featured_image',
      featuredImage: display,
      postID: postID,
      _wpnonce: $button.data('nonce')
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ajaxurl,
      data: data,
      success: function(response) {
        $button.removeAttr('disabled');
        console.log(response);
        if (response.featuredImage) {
          $button.text('Hide Featured Image');
          $button.attr('class', 'hide');
        } else {
          $button.text('Display Featured Image');
          $button.attr('class', 'show');
        }
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

### The result

The admin column appears with buttons for each post that has a featured image. The button text reflects whether or not the post meta is set to display the featured image. When you click on the button it toggles the status of this post meta value.

In your templates, all you have to do is get this post meta and use it to conditionally display the featured image.

```
$featured_image_display = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'show_featured_image' );
if ( $featured_image_display ) { 
    // Display featured image.
}
```